# Getting types from assembly adds " '1" at the end of some Type.Name

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

What I'm doing is getting all my referenced assemblies, then getting the types defined in the assembly. After looping it through and getting the Type.Name, most of the type name contains '1 at the end. What is the reason for this? Below is the code I'm currently using to strip it off:

```
AssemblyName[] assemblyNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();

      foreach (AssemblyName assemblyName in assemblyNames)
                {
                    if (assemblyName.Name == @namespace)
                    {
                        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);

                        var types = assembly.GetTypes().OrderBy(x => x.Name);
                        foreach (Type type in types)
                        {
                           if (!type.Name.Contains("1"))    //'1 is appearing at the end for some reason
                            cmbBoxCallFlowStage.Items.Add(type.Name);
                        else      
                            cmbBoxCallFlowStage.Items.Add(type.Name.Substring(0, type.Name.Length - 2));     //removing "'1" from the string
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are suffixes for generic types. Generic types in .NET are differently written than generic types in C#. The number after the quote denotes the number of generic type parameters.

Since .NET supports multiple classes in the same namespace with the same name but with different generic parameter count, there must be a difference somewhere. And that is where the backtick comes in.

Furthermore, Type.Name only shows the name of the type without namespaces and generic types. Use the fullname to view the fullname.

For example:

`List<int>` in c# is written as `` List`1[[System.Int32]] `` in .NET.

`Dictionary<string, long>` in c# is written as `` Dictionary`2[[System.String, System.Int64]] `` in .NET.

(My examples are a little shorter than the official form, but I wrote it to explain the meaning.)

Answer (score 0):

This suffix indicates the type's number of generic type parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Generic types have a `1,`2, etc appended to their type names for proper resolution.  This the CLR distinguish which generic type the type is for.